# Unable to open my live website from Github pages

Tags: wordpress, github

I have deployed my WordPress site to Github pages then from Github when I visit my live site I am facing this error:

> 404
>
> **File not found**
>
> The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.
>
> If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL as well as any file permissions.
> For root URLs (like `http://example.com/`) you must provide an `index.html` file.
>
> [Read the full documentation](https://help.github.com/pages/) for more information about using **GitHub Pages**.
>
> GitHub Status — [@githubstatus](https://twitter.com/githubstatus) .

How do I fix this?

I have changed the branch name and folder name. But it does not work.

Comment: FYI Github Pages only allows static sites. You can't use WordPress there.